# How to install build-essential on mac?

Tags: macos, build, debian, homebrew

`build-essential` installs fine on Debian/Ubuntu,

```
$ apt search build-essential
build-essential - Informational list of build-essential packages

$ sudo apt install build-essential
```

But does not appear to be available on brew/mac :

```
brew install build-essential
Error: No available formula with the name "build-essential" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
```

How do I install `build-essential` on Mac?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Homebrew (`brew`) is not the same as `apt-get`, and does not have the same packages. In particular, `build-essential` is not a Homebrew package. The package [`build-essential` is a Debian package](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=build-essential). From `apt show build-essential`,

> **If you do not plan to build Debian packages**, you don't need this
>    package.  Starting with `dpkg` (>= 1.14.18) this package is required
>    for building **Debian packages.**
>
> This package contains an informational list of packages which are
>    considered essential for building **Debian** packages.  This package also
>    depends on the packages on that list, to make it easy to have the
>    build-essential packages installed.

You can install compilers and supporting utilities with Xcode. First, download Xcode from the Mac App Store, and then run this in the terminal to install Xcode's command-line tools:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

(Although, if you already have Homebrew installed, you probably have Xcode and its command-line tools.)

Comment: Do I need to install Xcode just to install build-essential?