# Error while downloading pre-trained GAN model in Pytorch : 'memory' file not found

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I was following the steps given in https://modelzoo.co/model/pytorch-cyclegan-and-pix2pix to download a pre-trained model.

These where the first 3 commands given there:

```
git clone https://github.com/pytorch/vision
cd vision
**python setup.py install**
```

However when I ran the third line, I got an error:

```
fatal error: 'memory' file not found

#include <memory>

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

If anyone has some idea on how to overcome this error, it would be really helpful.

Comment: I use a Mac operating system. If you use a Linux OS refer cmxu's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [post](https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-ssl/issues/105). Try the line

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: build-essential is not available on mac.I saw other posts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086451/how-to-install-build-essential-on-mac, but its still not clear, how i can install it in mac. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I wasn't sure what OS you were using I just assume Linux, my bad. Did you figure it out? It would be using xcode.

Comment: Not yet, will tell you if i find it out, :)